# Use Unix timestamp as a condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table that is similar to the one below. As you can see, I have stored the dates as Unix timestamps. My goal is to only return the results which are for the upcoming dates, not the ones which are in past. How can I achieve this?

```
id    |   date
1       1331506800 //Mar 12 2012 
2       1366149600 //Apr 17 2013
3       1413928800 //Oct 22 2014
4       1436652000 //Jul 12 2015
```

Desire result:

```
id    |   date
1       1413928800 //Oct 22 2014
2       1436652000 //Jul 12 2015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: This is the best MySQL answer.

Comment: Thanks bro! I knew you had this one!

Comment: Watch the mysql keywords! Date is also a SQL function. So you have to place the name of the column in quotes like this:
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE \`date\` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: @Marcel: watch the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$h->query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE date > " . time());
```

This will also work in other databases than MySQL which do not have UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select * from table
where DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(dateColumn, '%e %b %Y %k:%i')),now())>0
```